# Splitting an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is the following equality true?

$$ \int_1^{2e} \left| \ln x - 1 \right| dx = \int_1^e(1-\ln x) dx + \int_e^{2e} (\ln x - 1) dx$$

Comment: $\ln(x)$ is strictly increasing and $\ln(e)=1$. Any bells ringing?

Comment: just look at the plot of $\ln(x)$, it will become clear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because $\ln x-1\geqslant 0$ for $x\geqslant \mathrm{e}$ and $\ln x-1\leqslant 0$ for $x\leqslant \mathrm{e}$.

Answer (score 2):

It's just replacing $|X|$ with $X$ or with $-X$ in ranges where $X$ is positive or negative, respectively, according to the modulus function definition.